# How to adjust editor scrolling in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, editor, application-settings, vertical-scrolling

I am using Android Studio 1.5.1 on Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bits.

When I scroll in a text editor window (like editing my MainActivity.java) it jumps 10 lines ahead (or back).

That's just too much scrolling for me.

I've already messed with the Settings/Editor/General/Scrolling options without any success. "Smooth Scrolling" has no effect on that.

I would like to change the scrolling for, like 1 line as I usually have in other windows applications, like windows explorer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is:
Appearance & Behavior -> Appearance ->  (window options - smooth scrolling). This will fix your side editor tabs.

Answer (score 0):

on windows 10: **go to settings -> devices -> mouse -> adjust *"choose how many lines to scroll each time"***

By adjusting it my scroll speed automatically reduced in android studio. But it will also reduce your scroll speed across the system like "scrolling web pages on browser" etc..

so it will be helpful to **experiment for a while and choose the best speed** that fits for you.

Answer (score 0):

if your using window 11 than go to **settings** and **Bluetooth & Devices** in scolling than select **mutlipe line at time** and how may line you want to scroll at time
[image]